# fsockopen(): unable to connect to unix

Tags: php, sockets, unix, ssh, php-deployer

I'm trying to make automatic website source deployment via [Deployer](http://deployer.org/) & SSH connect, but in built in deployer script there's connection using `fsockopen()` function and unix socket, and i always get following error: `Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to unix:///tmp/ssh-......5204:0 (Unable to find the socket tra
nsport "unix" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)`

I searched for similar issue about few hours, but can't find any information about same issue with PHP `fsockopen()` & unix socket.
Also i looked for my php.ini configuration and there's enabled openssl and provided extension directory, so i don't understand what mean:

> ...did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

from error note.

If who knows in what direction to look, please tell me.

P.S I'm using Windows OS and so for apache/php i use server platform OpenServer. (it's like WAMP, etc..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable sockets extension in your php.ini

`extension=php_sockets.dll`